# Consultas automáticas en PHP

Tags: php, javascript

he realizado una consulta y mostrado la información en una tabla hecha en php, la consulta esta todo bien el único detalle es que la tabla de la cual realice la consulta constantemente esta recibiendo información y quiero que la table que realice en php tome automáticamente la información de la tabla sin tener que recargar la pagina, he buscado sobre como poder hacer una tarea automática para que cierto tiempo recargue la pagina pero no he podido encontrar. AYUDA...!

Comment: ¿Estas hablando de una tabla en un servidor de base de datos a la cual consultas por php y queres hacer que javascript le haga un request a php para que le devuelva los datos?

Comment: lo que quiero es que al momento en que que se agrega un nuevo registro a la base aparezca también en la consulta php sin tener que recargar la pagina

Comment: Intenta usando Ajax, es fácil de usar y es justo para lo que quieres.

Comment: bueno @HenryParra aunque la verdad nunca he usado Ajax si pudieras ayudarme con algun tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar lo que quieres necesitas leer un algo de js. Con el siguiente código es una guía.
primero tendrías que colocar un div con un id respectivo en el body , luego ese div recargarlo través de js.

```
<div id="listado"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function listar(){
       $("#listado").load("../controlador/listarPersonas.php",function(){ //cargamos los datos de la consula  que realiza el listarPersonas.php  en  el <div id="listado">
        $('#listado').DataTable(); 
       });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){//cuando la pg inica...
      listar(); //llama la función, la cual lista las personas en un datatable        
    });

    $("#btn-grabar").click(function(){ // al hacer click en el boton grabar, iniciamos el regisro de la persona 

      var nombres          = $("#txtnombres").val(); //capturamos datos
      var apellidos        = $("#txtapellidos").val();//capturamos datos
      var direccion        = $("#txtdireccion").val();//capturamos datos
      var dni              = $("#txtdni").val();//capturamos datos
      var telefono         = $("#txttelefono").val();//capturamos datos
      var fechanac         = $("#txtfechanac").val();//capturamos datos
      var sexo             = $("#txtsexo").val();//capturamos datos

     $.post("../controlador/grabarPersona.php", {nombres:nombres, apellidos:apellidos, direccion:direccion,sexo:sexo,fechanac:fechanac, dni:dni,telefono:telefono})
           .done(function(data){ //enviamos los datos capturadoa a traves de post al archivo grabarPersona.php,
                                 //en el cual se realizará el registro
                     if (data == "ok"){ // si el registro devuelve "ok"..,
                       $('#myModal').modal('toggle');//cerramos el modal
                       listar(); //listamos las personas, 
                              //esto es lo que buscas que se acualice el listado de personas sin recargar la pagina
                     }
           });
    });
```

De hecho que faltan los archivos listarPersonas.php, grabarPersona.php, de hecho son los archivo que realizan la consulta y el registro, para eso te dejo un [**EJEMPLO**](http://simplesoftorg.scienceontheweb.net), para ingresar usa como Usuario: admin@admin.com y Password:123 ; en el modulo personas notaras que  cuando se registra, modifica o de cambia de estado, los datos se actualizan sin que la pagina se recargue. esto gracias a js.

Comment: ¿pero como le hago para que se haga cada cierto tiempo? o ¿con este procedimiento no es necesario agregar un intervalo de tiempo?
en mi caso solo es una consulta por intervalo de fechas, no actualizo ningún campo de la tabla.

Comment: Bueno es lo mismo simplemente la función listar(); se usaría cada vez que se cambie(change) los intervalos de fechas; te dejo un [EJEMPLO](http://jhotels.onlinewebshop.net) ("usuarioPrueba/12345"); con intervalos de fechas. Bueno si quiere que la función listar(); se active cada cierto tiempo existe varias formas, pero esta es básica, si quieres puedes utilizarla  <body onLoad="setInterval('listar()',5000);"> en esta forma nos dice que la funcion listar(); se recarga cada 5s.

Comment: pero en el caso que no sea una funcion y quiera recargar un <table> es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Si se puede, pero la pagina se recargaría, bueno eso es lo que no quieres que haga. Es necesario que lo hagas de esta forma(JS, AJAX), sino quieres refrescar la pagina. Eso era lo que preguntabas inicialmente.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que utilizar la [api de eventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) entonces tendrias algo asi como este script

```
var eventSource = new EventSource("stream_tabla.php");

eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    agregarElementoTabla(event.data);
};
```

Y un stream_tabla.php que se vea masomenos asi:

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

while(1){
    if(tablaActualizo()){
        $registroNuevo = obtenerRegistroNuevo();
        echo $registroNuevo;
        flush();
    }
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

[Este link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) de MDN puede darte mas informacion sobre el tema sobre los eventos enviados por el servidor.